# An Audio Module heating up

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, amplifier, audio, speakers

I am using an Audio Module. The schematics of the module can be found below. The module uses a audio amplifier (`TS4990IST`) and STM32F0 MCU.

I found out when powering up the module, the module start heating up. In my module, capacitor `C10` is not soldered. Can someone help me to rectify the issue?

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have been reading the datasheet of [TS4990](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ts4990.pdf) and found out it may require `Cin` capacitor at the input (Page 4). Find the screenshot of page 4 below:

[image]

Looks like the manufacturer of these modules has forget to add the `Cin` Capacitor and may be that's why the module is amplifying DC voltage and hence heating up the module. Am I right?

Comment: Check for spurious full scale oscillations and add C10  Often RC snubber is used across output.  <10 Ohms 0.1uF. Layout and wiring may have some effect as well as supply noise.

Comment: Could it be related to absence of input feed resistor?

Comment: R7 is feed input that affects gain (x1) thus phase margin or lack of it can cause spurious oscillation and self heating

Comment: Sorry, I mean input feed capacitor? The capacitor should block DC but it is not present in the module.

Comment: Is your source AC blocked?

Comment: Source is a DAC.

Comment: Please revert your edit which *removed* information from the question.

Comment: You could be right. Can you try to add the cap and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem maybe  Phase Margin is negative at unity gain (See Spec Fig 2) unless loaded with 560pF. See table...  65 deg unity gain phase margin with 8 Ohms 560 pF.

Check DC output across the load. If any DC, add DC blocking to the interface if your source is DC coupled with offset.  The 1uF draws power for 20~35 ms after Standby disable. This can be cancelled by RC matching input cap to rise at the same RC time constant.

> THis is a transient heat problem with coming out standby in this design on a 8 Ohm load.  Starting to heat up is OK. **Continuing to heat up is NOT OK.  If not continuing, it may be a non-problem.**

- If OK but you want to reduce the trasnsient heat effect,  change 1uF to   0.1uF. but note"*In the high frequency region, if Cs is lower than 1 µF, it increases THD+N and disturbances on the power supply rail are less filtered."*

You have 3 choices;

- increase gain to 20dB or x10 with Rf/Rin ratio.
- Add 500pF to each output. which at unity gain does not affect closed-loop BW significantly.
- some compromise of above.  R5=100k  gain ~x5 14dB , phase margin >30 deg stable  then test Step response for overshoot and add load Cap up to 560 pF

*It seems like the OEM designer did not figure out these issues.*

Comment: Source is analog voltage generated by DAC of STM32F0 controller. Do you think it requires DC blocking caps?

Comment: It depends on your DC noise and speed of V+ rise time, standby disable etc  ,, temp rise after 1 minute and application BW down to DC?

Comment: Is it hot 1 minute after startup?

Comment: It keeps on heating. Now the board has stopped working.

Comment: OK the it is oscillating and needs a low Z high f snubber and possibly better heat spreader.

Comment: You mean feed capacitor. I am testing the board now with oscilloscope.

Comment: no shunt snubber on outputs.. All linear power amps use them

Comment: I have checked. There is 2.6 V drop across the speaker.

Comment: Each amplifier must have same DC output to get 0 differential DC . CHeack all pins for error DC voltage. The second driver is just an inverter x-1  relative to CM bias V/2  = V bypass. You have an error somewhere.